# About the notion of limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$ if and only if  $\lim_{x \to c} f(x-c) = 0$

---

Consider the statement in the forward direction (1. $\Rightarrow$ 2.). If  $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$ (if $f: A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$), then we will have that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta_{1}>0$ such that $\forall x \in A, x \neq 0$ then $|x| < \delta_{1}$ implies $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ by definition of the limit.

I was thinking of letting $x-c = t$ and then we would have $|x-c|=|t|<\delta$ (if we choose $\delta$ to be $\delta < \delta_{1}$ ). Now, $|x-c| = |t| \neq 0$ as we require $x \neq c$. By definition, this would imply that $|f(t)| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |f(x-c)|<\epsilon$, thus completing the proof in one direction. However, I don't really understand if we can transfer this argument for $x$ to $t$ (what if $t=x-c \notin A$?).

What would be a more intuitive way to solve this problem? Or am I missing something simple? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you can answer your own question if you write out the definition of 2.

Comment: From the definition of 2., this implies $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x \in A, x \neq 0$ then if $|x-c|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x-c)|<\epsilon$ (which agrees from the result stated above). What I don't really understand is how we can transfer this definition from the variable $x$ to the new variable $t$.

Comment: But that 'definition' of 2. is wrong, the $\forall x\in A$ bit is incorrect, the correct set is not $A$.

Comment: Then what would the actual "new" set be? Wasn't the function $f$ defined from $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? Or would having $f(x-c)$ change it?